# Facebook Tab - Variables for mulitple pages

Tags: php, facebook, tabs

I want to make a system for tabs. I have a server with a database with different companies with there info. All the companies get a same tab, but with different content form the database.

The way I have to do it, is to make a new app (Tab app) for every company and link to the website like http://www.domainname.com/facebook.php?companyname=NAME.

I want a way that I can use 1 app for every company and only have to change the "companyname" variable. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Signed Request variable to get the page ID, which you then compare to all the entries you have in the database. Keep in mind, that you can only have 1 tab per page, but they will all use the same app.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

```
// create the Facebook Graph SDK object
require_once('facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'xxxx', // replace with your value
    'secret'=>'xxxx' // replace with your value
));
$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

// Get the page ID
$page_id = $signedRequest['page']['id'];
```

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I need. And my plan is to use 1 app a Fan-page. I'm going check it out how to implement it with my files. Thanks!

Comment: @Hopje123 Usually, if an answer works for you, you accept it here on StackOverflow. And I'm glad I could help!

Comment: How can i accept it? In the meaning, not to react and just use it?

Comment: There should be a tick icon underneath the vote count on the left side of the answer. Clicking that icon will accept this answer.